# Syntax error on simple while loop

Tags: bash, syntax

This general question has been asked many times and almost always there is an obvious syntax problem. But this seems correct:

```
cat mixed_encoded.txt |
while read i do
type=${"$(echo "$i" | file -bi -)"#*=}
if [[ $type == 'iso-8859-1' ]]; then
    echo "$i" | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
else
    echo "$i"
fi
done > utf8_encoded.txt
```

gives

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

Whether pasted as multiline or in one-line mode. With or without the final `> utf8_encoded.txt`. With the inner quotes escaped or not.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try and put the `while` right after the pipe in the previous line.

Comment: Don't use `cat` to loop over files

Comment: Don't use `cat` to loop over *single* files (`cat filea fileb | while ...` is fine, assuming it is ok to run the loop in a subshell). For single files, `while ...; done < mixed_encoded.txt` is the preferred style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat mixed_encoded.txt |
while read i; do
type=${"$(echo "$i" | file -bi -)"#*=}
if [[ $type == 'iso-8859-1' ]]; then
    echo "$i" | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
else
    echo "$i"
fi
done > utf8_encoded.txt
```

You are missing a semicolon.

This only fixes the unexpected `done` token.  The substitution is still bad.

This edit fixes the bad substitution:

```
cat mixed_encoded.txt |
while read i; do
type=$(echo "$i" | file -b --mime-encoding -)
if [[ $type == 'iso-8859-1' ]]; then
    echo "$i" | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
else
    echo "$i"
fi
done > utf8_encoded.txt
```

Comment: The semi colon is not necessary before the newline.

Comment: But it is necessary before the `do`

Comment: You need either a semi-colon or a newline before the `do`, but not both.

Comment: I too thought that was the rule but the syntax error is fixed by the semicolon.

Comment: @user3343285 You need an eol or `;` before the `do`. You have it after